# run bash command outside docker container

Tags: docker, fastapi

I built API using FastAPI that calls some bash commands. Now I want to make a docker container for my app but I encountered the following issue: if I create a docker container, the app won't run bash commands. I guess I need to get out of docker container to run bash commands but I am not sure that it is possible. Any suggestions? Apologies in advance if my question is confusing.
Here is my Docker File

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

# CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

and here is an example of how I run bash command (it is actually a docker command)

```
@app.post("/stop-camera")
async def stop_camera(info: Request):
    req_info =  await info.json()
    file_name = str(req_info["id"])
    result1 = subprocess.run([str(env_dictionary["STOP"])+ file_name], shell = True)
    result2 = subprocess.run([str(env_dictionary["REMOVE"])+ file_name], shell = True)

    return {
        "status" : "SUCCESS",
        "stop" : result1,
        "rm" : result2
    }
```

Comment: How did you build your container? Does it contain a `bash` interpreter? How are you trying to run `bash`? Do you get error messages?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I run bash commands using python subprocess library inside my app. I did not get any specific errors. It is just giving me Internal Server Error because bash commands cannot be run while in docker container

Comment: Please click [edit] and add your dockerfile into your question rather than in the comments. Thank you,

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you sm for your help. I added the code into the question

Comment: first: you can always `exec` into your container and test the stuff you want to do manually. second: i sincerely hope this is some private stuff for your rasppi on a closed network, because passing generic strings from your request body to a shell subprocess is a huuuuuge problem securitywise.

Comment: @MarkSetchell STOP command and filename has to be concatenated in my particular case.

Comment: I think I misread your question. The shell script you want to run from *inside* your container is actually *outside* your container? In that case I think you're going to have to signal to some proxy outside to run it on your behalf.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes exactly, I need to run outside script from the inside. Could you please clarify about your suggestion with proxy? Thank you!

Comment: I mean something outside docker that does the STOP on your behalf. So a script, outside docker, subscribed to MQTT that waits for your docker container to publish a STOP message and then stops whatever it is for you. Or likewise a script that waits on a Redis LIST for a STOP message and then does the stopping for you. Or a script, outside docker that reads from a named pipe in the filesystem over a docker `bind mount` and your docker process writes the word STOP into that file/pipe and the external process's `read` off the pipe then succeeds and it then does the stopping for you.

Comment: I am no docker expert so this might be very clumsy, or ill-advised. I just guess it should work.

Comment: I guess you could write to a UDP port on your host fairly simply from Python within docker, and have a script waiting on a UDP read outside of docker that does the stopping when the read is successful. That is pretty simple with Python, or in `bash` using `netcat` or built-in read from `/dev/udp/...`

Comment: From an architectural point of view, is this really what should be done? A container is meant to live for it's own and be portable between hosts. It should therefore not directly access things on the host.

Comment: @Henry As I said, I am no docker expert and it may not be advisable even though I tested it and found it works so I added it as an answer. Please add a better answer if you have one and I can happily delete mine - we are all here to learn :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell my comment was more directed to the original question rather than your answer.

Comment: You've gone very quiet- did you try my answer? What happened? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example of UDP communication between something running on a docker host and something running inside a container.

---

On the host, start a simple docker container passing it a way to get the host's IP address:

```
docker run -it --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway alpine:latest ash
```

Then, still outside the container and on the host, wait for a command on UDP port 65000 from the container. Note I am using `netcat` here, but you would likely use Python since you have that already:

```
# Listen on UDP port 65000
nc -u -l 65000
```

Obviously you could run this in a loop to wait for multiple commands, and you could parse different commands that arrive and react differently to different commands and you could also check the source of the commands, or encrypt them for some level of security...

---

Inside the container, I quickly add `netcat` but you would probably use Python again:

```
# Install netcat
apk update && apk install netcat-openbsd

# Send command to host via UDP on port 65000
echo STOP | nc -u host.docker.internal 65000
```